# Can we play a message and an mp3 as waitUrl in Twilio conferencing?

Tags: c#, .net-core, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I have an application where two calls are connected to a conference via Twilio. In the current implementation what happens is, when the first call is answered, a message using `<Say>` attribute is played and then is dialled into a conference. While the other person connects, there is an mp3 added as the `waitUrl`. The code for this is shown below.

```
 var dial = new Dial()
                    .Conference(sessionId.ToString(),
                    startConferenceOnEnter: true,
                    waitUrl: new Uri(this.musicUrl),
                    waitMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                    statusCallbackEvent: callbackEvents,
                    statusCallback: new Uri("url")
                );

                response.Say(message).Append(dial);
```

My question is, Is it possible to play a message, then the mp3 within the waitUrl instead of adding `<Say>` before dialling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the waitUrl as an attribute that can be updated in a conference, as shown in the documentation here.

[Conference Resource (Update a Conference Resource)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-resource#update-a-conference-resource)

You can look at the Conference Participants API / [Agent Conference Create a Participant option](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only) and earlyMedia set to true and then update the [announceUrl](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/twilio-conference-now-supports-announcements.html) to play updates to a participant or all participants. It is not clear from your question what information you are trying to convey to the participant(s).

Comment: What I'm trying is to see whether we can play the mp3  with a `<say>` attribute, instead of adding the `<say>` before dialling. Something similar to this.                                                                                `waitUrl: new Uri("url"),
 waitMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,`    and within that url                                                         `.Say(message, voice: this.voice)
.Play(new Uri(this.musicUrl));`

Comment: What is the .mp3 telling the participant?

Comment: the mp3 is music that will play until the second call get's connected

Comment: For the `Say`, what you are doing before adding the first participant to the conference is correct.

Comment: This is not regarding this question, but one of my test runs didn't completed properly and now there are two call that are still in progress and they are not ending even though both the calls are ended. I know we can use https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json?Status=completed to complete the call. But it's not working. Any suggestions to end the calls

Comment: In a conference? Using the Calls Resource to end a call should work or trying modifying the call legs and pointing  them to an Empty TwiML document (with an `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response></Response>` - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress.